# How to run npm install on github

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, parse-server, github-for-mac

I would like to run `npm install` on GitHub. I tried doing so by cloning the repository through GitHub Desktop, but nothing happens on the online copy of the repo when I commit the changes.

I am trying to do this for parse-server.

Comment: What do you mean run it on Github? Are you trying to serve your application from it's Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to commit npm packges (it's not advised to do so though), remove `/node_modules` from your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Check your GitHub repo if there's one, the file is hidden when viewed under file system. Alternatively, you can run `git add ./node_modules/* -f`, `-f` will add it to git even if it is ignored.

Comment: Exactly that's the problem, I don't know where to run the commands.

Comment: Github isn't a hosting service. You can't run commands on it.

Comment: @IanAuld Thank you. I've tried to run commands from the cloned directory on my desktop and commit changes through the GitHub Desktop app, but nothing is sent updated online.

Comment: you need to push the changes for them to show up on GitHub. [Here](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) is a very simple guide for using git.